# Add __getitem__ function to COM object in Python, OR: Overriding __slots__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, com, pywin32

### Goal

I'm working with pywin32 and win32com to manipulate COM objects from a third-party application.

One of my objects is a list, and I would like to iterate over the values in a list comprehension.

### What works

With some of the COM objects I am able to successfully do things like:

```py
>>> [obj.Name for obj in myCom.someList if 'Test' in obj.Name]
```

And, as expected, I get a list of results:

`['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']`

### What doesn't...

However, on other similar list objects I try the same thing:

```py
>>> [obj.Name for obj in myCom.anotherList]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\<class_string>.py", line 6575, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("This object does not support enumeration")
TypeError: This object does not support enumeration
```

### What I've tried

So I try to add the function after defining `my_iter`:

```py
>>> myCom.anotherList.__iter__ = my_iter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 473, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Thingy instance at 0xDEADBEEF>' object has no attribute '__iter__'
```

I tried the same thing with `__getitem__` and `next` and I get the same error. I did some reading and I assumed that this doesn't work because of something to do with `__slots__`... Not sure.

### Examining generated Python source

After examining .py shown in the first stack trace, I looked at the definition of `class ISomeList.__iter__` - since that worked perfectly in the first example in the post.

```py
from win32com.client import DispatchBaseClass
LCID = 0x0
class ISomeList(DispatchBaseClass):
    def __iter__(self):
        "Return a Python iterator for this object"
        try:
            ob = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(-4,LCID,2,(13, 10),())
        except pythoncom.error:
            raise TypeError("This object does not support enumeration")
        return win32com.client.util.Iterator(ob, '{<<<guid>>>}')
```

And compare that to `class IAnotherList.__init__`:

```py
class IAnotherList(DispatchBaseClass):
    def __iter__(self):
        "Return a Python iterator for this object"
        try:
            ob = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(-4,LCID,3,(13, 10),())
        except pythoncom.error:
            raise TypeError("This object does not support enumeration")
        return win32com.client.util.Iterator(ob, None)
```

So, to me, it looks like assigning to `ob` fails and then we raise an error.

I can modify the generated source to add the `__iter__` method, but that seems like a very "works on my machine" solution. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

I'm very open to any alternative approaches, but this is what I came up with on my own.

I discovered that there is a win32com helper function called `GetModuleForProgID` - as you might expect from the name, it will take the COM Program ID and return the pywin32 module that was generated to wrap that object.

### The code

What ended up working best for me was:

```
""" define a method to do my iteration """
def com_generic_iter(self):
    current = 1 """ All the com objects I'm working with are 1-based indeces """
    while current <= self.Count:
        yield self.Item(current)
        current += 1

""" I also wanted to support __getitem__ indexing: """
def generic_getitem(self, k):
    return self.Item(k)

""" Then dynamically add the method to the application wrapper when I generate my object """
mod = win32com.client.gencache.GetModuleForProgID("MyProgram.Application")
mod.IAnotherList.__iter__ = com_generic_iter
mod.IAnotherList.__getitem__ = generic_getitem
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("MyProgram.Application")

print [x.Name for x in app.AnotherList]

"""
[<win32com.gen_py.MyProgram.IItem instance at 0x12345678>,
 <win32com.gen_py.MyProgram.IItem instance at 0x87654321>,
 <win32com.gen_py.MyProgram.IDifferentItem instance at 0x99999999>]
"""

print app.AnotherList[1]

"""
<win32com.gen_py.MyProgram.IItem instance at 0x12345678>
"""
```

### Edit:

You can also add `__iter__` and `__getitem__` with `setattr` like this:

```
mod = win32com.client.gencache.GetModuleForProgID("MyProgram.Application")
IAnotherList = mod.IAnotherList
setattr(IAnotherList, '__getitem__', generic_getitem)   
setattr(IAnotherList, '__iter__', com_generic_iter)
```

### Sources

I used [win32com documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/GeneratedSupport.html) to find details about `GetModuleForProgID`.